# How are filters created?

Tags: support, api-v2, filter

Can someone explain how Filters are created in the Stackexchange v2 API?

The documentation mentions the following for /filters/create:

> It is not expected that many applications will call this method at runtime, filters should be pre-calculated and "baked in" in the common cases.

Not sure what this means. Would be really helpful if someone constructed an example URL to make this call.

Answer (score 6):

Filters are created by sending `include`, `exclude`, and `base` to [/filters/create](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter).  You can use GET for rapid prototyping, or POST when the amount of data you're sending grows too large for a GET.

`base` specifies a filter to use as a template.  It is the "default" filter, by default.  A blank slate can be achieved by using "none".

`include` and `exclude` contain semi-colon delimited lists of fields to add or remove from the `base` filter.  For example, `include=.total;question.body` says to return the `total` field on the [common wrapper object](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper) and question bodies (provided you call a method that returns questions, naturally).

We provide a utility in the console on every method page (see [/questions](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) for example) to make building filters easier.

[image]
<sub>When you save, the created filter will be placed where the "editing..." box is.</sub>

> ...filters should be pre-calculated and "baked in" in the common cases

Simply means that the vast majority of applications *shouldn't* call /filters/create as part of their normal operation.  An apps developer should have pre-calculated the filters the app needs, and hard-coded them in basically.  Note, filters are immutably and non-expiring so this "bake in" is perfectly safe.

Comment: Is it possible to Name these saved filters instead of resorting to the pre-configured name?

Comment: @kevin-montrose I think it would be helpful if the [docs on this page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter) mentioned the part about using a semicolon as a delimiter in the `create` call